# PIG - retrieve data from XML using XPATH

Tags: hadoop, xpath, xml-parsing, apache-pig

I **have n number** of these type of xml files.

```
<students roll_no=1>
    <name>abc</name>
    <gender>m</gender>
    <maxmarks>
        <marks>
            <year>2014</year>
            <maths>100</maths>
            <english>100</english>
            <spanish>100</spanish>
        <marks>
        <marks>
            <year>2015</year>
            <maths>110</maths>
            <english>110</english>
            <spanish>110</spanish>
        <marks>
    </maxmarks>
    <marksobt>
        <marks>
            <year>2014</year>
            <maths>90</maths>
            <english>95</english>
            <spanish>82</spanish>
        <marks>
        <marks>
            <year>2015</year>
            <maths>94</maths>
            <english>98</english>
            <spanish>02</spanish>
        <marks>
    </marksobt>
</Students>
```

I need output like

```
roll_no name    gender  year    eng_max_marks   maths_max_marks spanish_max_marks
1       abc     m       2014    100                 100          100
1       abc     m       2015    110                 110          110
```

I am able to retrieve marks row wise in single statement but not able to extract roll_no and name with this.

```
A =  LOAD 'student.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('marks') as (x:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x, 'marks/year'), XPath(x, 'marks/english'), XPath(x, 'marks/math'), XPath(x, 'marks/spanish');
```

This return

```
year    eng_max_marks   maths_max_marks spanish_max_marks
2014    100              100             100
2015    110              110             110
```

I can extract both the chunks but not getting how to join other fields. I can't use across join because I have n number of other files.

Let's forger attribute name (roll_no) for now. How can I extract the rest of nodes

```
name    gender  year    eng_max_marks   maths_max_marks spanish_max_marks
abc      m     2014      100             100             100
abc      m     2015      110             110             110
```

I don't want to use marks(1)/english approach because this nodes can also vary and don't want to adopt any dirty approach.

Any pointers????

Comment: I only know XPath and I am not familiar with your framework or platform you use XPath with. With normal XPath you can simply navigate up the tree to select the other data e.g. `XPath(x, 'ancestor::students/@roll_no')`, `XPath(x, `ancestor::students/name`)`. If you can't do that then perhaps you can first load the root element `students` with e.g. `A =  LOAD 'student.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('students') as (x:chararray);` and then use `XPathAll(A, 'students/maxmarks/marks')` to select the `marks` elements and use your `FOREACH` over that result.

Comment: Then I have to use index for all child node which I don't want to use. For this I need to repeat that chunk of code n times. N = no of times child exists and this can also vary.

Comment: I think I have to write UDF for this n return type would be tuple but not sure.. Any thought???

Comment: I think tuple can handle the multiple rows returned by the UDF but will try this