# Apache Pig - Transform data bag to set of rows

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig data

```
(123,{(1),(2),(3)},{(0.5),(0.6),(0.7)})
```

I want to generate records in below format

```
123,1,0.5
123,2,0.6
123,3,0.7
```

I am able to do this when above data has one bag but not getting how to generate required output when we have multiple data bags.

Any Suggestions????

Comment: Could you give actual inputs in terms of records. How you created that input.

Comment: Sorry, can't share the actual input. I created  it thru XML in which 1st field is chararray and rest r data bags. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33044358/pig-retrieve-data-from-xml-using-xpath#comment53932971_33044358
XML file in this question is just a replica of what I have. Please have a look.